# ASP.NET MVC Mulitlingual site not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm working on a website that must be in both English and Spanish. I have used resx files and am adapting the culture setting based on the browser's language setting as the code below shows (this is on the global.asax.cs):

```
        protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string culture = "en-US";
        if (Request.UserLanguages != null)
        {
            culture = Request.UserLanguages[0];
        }
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);
    }
```

This does work! However, the user should also be able to change the language. To accomplish this, so I created a CultureController as my code below shows, which is consumed by the site through a link:

```
    public class CultureController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SetLanguage(string name)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(name);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["culture"] = name;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

}
```

And I have these links on my site:

```
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("SetLanguage", "Culture", new { @name = "es-ES" })">Español</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("SetLanguage", "Culture", new { @name = "en-US" })">English</a></li>
```

This does not work. It's weird, cause when I debug it the method is actually used and the data flow seems correct, it gets the name parameter and sets it, but after the redirection the language does not change and the requests are shown as failed. Do you have any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You set `Session["culture"]`. I would then expect there is also code that reads it, please [edit] the question to show where and how you (try to) apply the stored value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would using a different URL for the languages work?

I did that at a previous employer, so that we didn't have to change one's browser language in order to test the different languages, and also if that a user prefers one language over another (situationally) but their browser isn't configured correctly, they have control.

Example:

http://example.com/en/home vs http://example.com/es/home

I was able to use URL rewriting to extract that into a querystring parameter (quite unnecessary with MVC as you can use routing parameters)

You could quite easily add some code to detect browser language and redirect the user to the correct URL, and allow a cookie to override these preferences.

I'm aware that this is a vastly different answer than you were looking for, but it made it a snap to test ("/en/" was a hack we didn't actually set up per se; I just made it work so that we could debug the pages without having to translate the text.)

It was quite easy to throw up the 6 versions of the page in different tabs and check that everything looked correct. We had German and Chinese, and those are good test languages: German nouns get *long*, and it's very easy to determine if you missed translating any phrases with Chinese.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! Although it really was a vastly different answer than I was looking for, it's a neat solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have route for localization.First you have to define routes like below.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
           name: "LocalizedDefault",
           url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
           constraints: new {lang="es-ES|fr-FR|en-US"}
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", lang = en-US }
        );
```

After setting thread language you have to direct it with lang like below.

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.RedirectToRoute("LocalizedDefault", 
            new { lang=culture,
                    controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"],
                    action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
            });
            return;
```

For full implementation have a look at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1160340/Get-insight-to-build-your-first-Multi-Language-ASP) article.